# geometric charaterization of complex interpolation spaces $(H,Y)_\theta$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $C$ be the class of Banach spaces $X$ such that there exists $0<\theta<1$, a Hilbert space $H$ and a Banach space $Y$ such that
$$
X=(H,Y)_\theta
$$
(complex interpolation of Calderon).

Does there exist a geometric charaterization of this class of Banach spaces?

I know that a Banach space $X$ in $C$ is uniformly convex.